# I get the wrong length from class.length

Tags: javascript, html, loops, class, for-loop

I'm trying to make divs appear according to the number of elements in the class, but instead, I get the number of arguments that are in the constructor. the creating of divs is already working but I just don't get the right number of divs.

Does anyone know how to get the length of the items in the class, in this case, I need it to be 4 items.

```js
let toggleButton = document.getElementById('toggle-button-id')
let toggleStateSquare = false;

class Block {
  constructor(title, description) {
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
  }
}

var block1 = new Block('lieke', 'lorem ipsum dolor nogwattes');
var block2 = new Block('testjete', 'ldjfaoef aheoahf aflheaofhia afhoeahfoa ef aohfhoa');
var block3 = new Block('testte', 'ldjfaoef aheoahf aflheaofhia afhoeahfoa ef aohfhoa');
var block4 = new Block('rqed', 'lorem ipsum dofafdaffelor nogwattes');

console.log(Block.length)

createElements()
let elementsArray = document.querySelectorAll('.element')
setElementHeight()


function setElementHeight() {
  elementHeight = document.getElementsByClassName("element")[0].clientWidth + 'px';
  for (var i = 0; i < elementsArray.length; i++) {
    elementsArray[i].style.height = elementHeight;
  }
}

function createElements() {
  for (var i = 0; i < Block.length; i++) {
    console.log('test', i)
    var block = document.createElement('div');
    block.setAttribute('class', 'element');
    block.setAttribute('id', `elementid${i+1}`);
    document.getElementById('grid-container-id').appendChild(block);
    console.log('block aangemaakt')
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.grid-container {
  padding: 40px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  /* grid-auto-rows:220px; */
  grid-gap: 40px;
}

.element {
  background: #4287f5;
  /* grid-column: span 2; */
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding: 20px;
}

h2 {
  color: white;
}

p {
  color: white;
}

.toggle-button-class {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- import fontawesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id='grid-container-id' class="grid-container">

  </div>
  <div class='toggle-button-class' id='toggle-button-id'><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i></div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can't do `Block.length` to get the number of instances of the class that have been created. Instead, store them in an array.

Comment: I think you mean "number of class instances", right? "Items in the class" sounds like class properties.

Comment: I want to get the number of these four blocks

`var block1 = new Block('lieke', 'lorem ipsum dolor nogwattes');

var block2 = new Block('testjete', 'ldjfaoef aheoahf aflheaofhia afhoeahfoa ef aohfhoa');

var block3 = new Block('testte', 'ldjfaoef aheoahf aflheaofhia afhoeahfoa ef aohfhoa');

var block4 = new Block('rqed', 'lorem ipsum dofafdaffelor nogwattes');`

Comment: `var blocks = [ new Block(...), new Block(...), new Block(...), new Block(...) ]`. You can then iterate over `blocks`.

Comment: Thanks that solved it thanks for your time.

Comment: Here's an example that I created for you: https://jsfiddle.net/espressobeans/6so5jpbv/